# why system call need interrupt

Tags: linux, operating-system

why systemCall need a interrupt rather than directly call kernel code .  i think in protected mode ,the user's process can not get the kernel address ,so need interrupt to come to the kernel address ,is it true?

Comment: yes that is true

Answer (score -2):

It's not an interrupt. It is an EXCEPTION. An exception is required to change the processor mode.